# SSE Load Neighboring Values

Tags: c++, x86, sse, simd

A common thing when dealing with 2D arrays is to load a set of values then shift them to the left or right then load 1 more value into the value that is no longer needed. What is the best way to do this??

```
float arr[128][128];

for(int i = 1;i < 127;++i)
for(int j = 1;j < 127;++j)
{
 __m128 top = _mm_load_ps(arr[i - 1][j]);
 __m128 center = _mm_load_ps(arr[i][j]);

 //...stuff

 //rotate the top
 top = _mm_shuffle_ps(top,top,_MM_SHUFFLE(0,3,2,1));
 //how do i load another item in without insert?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about doing neighbourhood operations on 2D data then to get vectors which are shifted left or right by some amount you can either use unaligned loads or if you can assume SSSE3 or later, use `_mm_alignr_epi8`. Normally you'd only use the unaligned load method on old CPUs with SSE3 or below where you have no other options.

Examples for operating on vectors shifted left/right by 1 float element:

Unaligned loads:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 128; j += 4)
{
    vl = _mm_loadu_ps(&a[i][j-1]);       // left shifted vector
    vm = _mm_load_ps(&a[i][j]);          // middle vector
    vr = _mm_loadu_ps(&a[i][j+1]);       // right shifted vector
}
```

`_mm_alignr_epi8`:

```
va = _mm_setzero_ps();
vb = _mm_load_ps(&a[i][0]); 
for (int j = 0; j < 128; j += 4)
{
    vc = _mm_load_ps(&a[i][j+4]); 
    vl = _mm_alignr_epi8(va, vb, sizeof(float));       // left shifted vector
                                                       // middle vector = vb
    vr = _mm_alignr_epi8(vb, vc, 3 * sizeof(float));   // right shifted vector
    va = vb;                                           // shuffle source vectors left by one
    vb = vc;
}
```

Note that when you are performing a lot of neighbourhood operations with a large number of different shifts it's sometimes more efficient to transpose the whole block of data temporarily so that you just use row indexing rather than having to do horizontal vector operations such as the above.